# Using matplotlib, how do I move the xlabels to the top and center all labels between gridlines?

Tags: python, matplotlib, label

I am trying to create a 10x10 grid where each cell is either black or white. I have it mostly working the way I want, but I want to move the x-labels to the top of the grid and I want all labels to be centered between the grid lines not aligned with them. How do I go about this?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# data = random.random((10, 10))
face = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]

img = plt.imshow(face, interpolation='nearest')

img.set_cmap('hot')
plt.axis('on')
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 11, 1) - 0.5, np.arange(0, 11, 1))
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 11, 1) - 0.5, np.arange(0, 11, 1))
plt.grid(True, linestyle='dotted', linewidth=1, color='k')
plt.plot()
plt.savefig("test.png", bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, use `matshow` instead of `imshow`. Also, use `minor` ticks for labeling:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
img = ax.matshow(face, interpolation='nearest', cmap='hot')

ax.set_xticks(np.arange(10), minor=True)
ax.set_xticklabels(np.arange(10), minor=True)

ax.set_yticks(np.arange(10), minor=True)
ax.set_yticklabels(np.arange(10), minor=True)

plt.xticks(np.arange(11)-0.5,[])
plt.yticks(np.arange(11)-0.5,[])

plt.grid(True, linestyle='dotted', linewidth=1, color='k')
plt.plot()
# plt.savefig("test.png", bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]